# @BeanProperty with PropertyChangeListener support?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, javabeans, propertychangesupport

`@BeanProperty` generates simple `get`/`set` methods. Is there a way to automatically generate such methods with support for firing property change events (e.g. I want to use it with JFace Databinding?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same question, and have been keeping a close eye out for possible answers.  I think I've just stumbled across one (although I haven't tried it yet).  Scala 2.9 has a feature for handling dynamic calls (meant for integration with dynamic languages, I suspect).  Essentially, calls to methods which don't exist are routed to a method called applyDynamic.  An implementation of that method could use reflection to check that the method signature matches a property (possibly one with an annotation similar to @BeanProperty).  If there is a match, it could handle firing the event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's something where a custom compiler plugin can do the trick.
Sadly I have no idea about how to write such a plugin. But at least thought I give you this pointer.

I would be **very** interested, if you'd come up with something along that line.